# Unable to configure perforce with Code Collaborator on mac

Tags: macos, mac, perforce

I tried to setup Code Collaborator on Mac with Perforce but I get the following error

```
Error: Error while processing output
```

Not sure what I should do to fix it :(

Comment: Are you trying to setup the Code Collaborator client?  I don't have access to it anymore, but if I remember correctly there is an option in the UI to get additional logging information.  That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the resolution.

I had to get the latest perforce command line client from the website.